# Java Stream filter - how can i filter data without wrapping the filter code in 'if' condition for checking null on the filtering keys?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am doing the following:

```
List<Objects> filtered = objects.stream()
    .filter(o -> source.equals(o.getSource()) && date.equals(o.getDate()) && id.equals(o.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where both `date` and `id` could possibiliy be `null`, as the are coming from method parameters.

How can I ignore them if null, without wrapping the above code in an if statement tp check 'id' and 'date' for null values ? I want to do it inside the filter.

Edit : To make it more clear, i want the filter to act only on the non-null values, i.e if date is non-null and id is null, then filter only on date and ignore id, and so on..

Thanks

Comment: *checking 'id' and 'date' explicitly for null values*: what do you mean? you can't ignore them if they're null without checking for nulls....

Comment: i dont want to wrap the above command in an if block.. can i do it inside stream or filter ? That is because if either 'date' or 'id' are null, i want the filter to act on only the non-null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An additional option is to do the null checks in the predicate:

```
.filter(o -> source.equals(o.getSource()) 
             && (null == date || date.equals(o.getDate()))
             && (null == id || id.equals(o.getId())))
```

Comment: Thanks !! This answers my question !

Comment: @biokikoi If this is best answer for your question, you can "thank" the answerer by voting and accepting the answer, see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should generally vote up any answer you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the static method `Objects::equals`. Chances are that this method is designed for just this:

```
List<Objects> filtered = objects.stream()
    .filter(o -> Objects.equals(source, o.getSource()) && Objects.equals(date, o.getDate()) && Objects.equals(id, o.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: as Scratte mentioned in the comments, this may not filter out objects for which `getDate()` returns `null`, if `date` is also `null`. Same goes for `id`. If that's the case, then the abovementioned code snippet does not comply. In that case, then we have to explicitly filter for non-null dates and ids:

```
.filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o.getId()) && Objects.nonNull(o.getDate()))
```

---

#### Update

If you want to skip the comparison for `getDate()` if `date` is `null` (and same for `id`), then you could check first for `null`, just like in [ernest_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258678/507738).

You could easily build a small method for it:

```
public static boolean nullOrEquals(Object baseObject, Object compareObject) {
    return baseObject == null || Objects.equals(baseObject, compareObject);
}
```

```
.filter(o -> Objects.equals(source, o.getSource())
    && nullOrEquals(date, o.getDate())
    && nullOrEquals(id, o.getId()))
```

[Here's an Ideone example](https://ideone.com/warTdK).

Comment: With the caveat that if both arguments to `Objects.equals` are `null`, it will return `true`.

Comment: @Scratte Good catch.

Comment: Thanks MC. ernest's answer helps my case, but thanks for your answer as well .. new learning for me :)